# Xaml nested event is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid with an tap event and in this grid three more buttons with click event. The first (the middle) button is working, but the others are not. If I click on it the grid event is fired instead of the button event. And i didn't know why?

```
<Page
....
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource BackgroundBrush}"  Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="130"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="#BEBEBE"/>

    <Border Grid.Row="3" Background="#BEBEBE"/>
    ....
    <Button x:Name="btnGoToContent" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,20" Height="80" Width="320" Click="btnGoToContent_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle2}" Opacity="0.7"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnDiashowBack" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="220" Width="220" Click="btnDiashowBack_Click" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Opacity="0.7"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnDiashowNext" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="220" Width="220" Click="btnDiashowNext_Click" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonMirror}" Opacity="0.7"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You have a tapped event on the parent. Try adding ClickMode="Press" on your buttons.

Comment: doesn't solve it. But the button event is fired and after this the tapped event

Comment: Ok I kind of figured that may be the case (didn't test) so you'll just need to separate those Hit areas. Move your Tapped event to one of those Borders that appears behind the Buttons instead of applying it to the parent of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it isn't working. But I've solved it with this Workaround. Skip the event in the grid event handler

```
   private async void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.OriginalSource.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock)) 
        {
            return;
        }
        .......
   }
```